# What happens to the bounty if there's no answer?

Tags: support, bounty

Last week I [started a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81132/ratio-of-probabilities-vs-ratio-of-pdfs) which got not answers so I set up a bounty. The [Help center](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) states:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's
>   no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

What does `the bounty is not awarded to anyone` mean? Do the points come back to me or are they lost?

Ok I just stumbled upon this question [Unclaimed bounty points: where did they go?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/unclaimed-bounty-points-where-did-they-go) (which makes mine a duplicate) and apparently I loose the points. How is this fair?

Comment: Just voted to close my own question given that I recognize it to be a duplicate.